# Do I need to develope a new function in MOODLE to get a web service that return the list of session by couse using attendance plugin?

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api

so I'm using MOODLE 3.11.3+ (Build: 20211019) and we exposed a number of web services.
we need to use the attendance [plugin](https://moodle.org/plugins/mod_attendance) and I'd like very much to get the list of sessions by course, is that possible without touching the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Moodle, the web service functions are usually in `externallib.php` or `pluginname\classes\external.php`

So for the attendance activity they are in

https://github.com/danmarsden/moodle-mod_attendance/blob/MOODLE_311_STABLE/externallib.php

There are a couple of related functions like `get_courses_with_today_sessions()` and `get_session()` but not a list of sessions for a course.

If you have access to the database, then you could use something like

```
SELECT *
FROM {course} c
JOIN {attendance} a ON a.course = c.id
JOIN {attendance_sessions} s ON s.attendanceid = a.id
```